# Using JQuery inside repeater item for update / remove database record

Tags: asp.net, ajax, database, repeater

Is it possible to use Ajax or JQuery inside asp.net repeater items, i.e. on button click, to update or delete database record without refresh or rendering the page?

Comment: Why can't you use a Gridview instead?

Answer (score 2):

ya sure, give buttons a css class and bind the click event of that button to do what you need

```
$(dcoument).ready(function(){
  $('.Update').click(function(){
    // do something
  });
})
```

**Easier solution** is to use GridView with update panel to update without refresh the page
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/GridView---Add-Edit-Update-Delete-and-Paging-the-AJAX-way.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386452%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: make an ajax call to server where @Michael B commented with `// do something`